# Golang Avro Convert to stuct

Tags: go, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, avro

I am trying to read kafka message and convert that from avro format to golang struct.

```
avroSchemaJSON := {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Value",
        "namespace": "aw.skeletor.public.user_hierarchy_new",
        "fields": [
            {"name": "userrole_id", "type": {"type": "string", "connect.version": 1, "connect.name": "io.debezium.data.Uuid"}},
            {"name": "organistion_id", "type": ["null", {"type": "string", "connect.version": 1, "connect.name": "io.debezium.data.Uuid"}], "default": null},
            {"name": "reporting_to_id", "type": ["null", {"type": "string", "connect.version": 1, "connect.name": "io.debezium.data.Uuid"}], "default": null},
            {"name": "user_id", "type": ["null", {"type": "string", "connect.version": 1, "connect.name": "io.debezium.data.Uuid"}], "default": null},
            {"name": "name", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},
            {"name": "msisdn", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},
            {"name": "email", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},
            {"name": "olm_id", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},
            {"name": "tenant_id", "type": ["null", {"type": "string", "connect.version": 1, "connect.name": "io.debezium.data.Uuid"}], "default": null},
            {"name": "operating_boundaries", "type": ["null", {"type": "array", "items": ["null", "string"]}], "default": null},
            {"name": "role_level", "type": ["null", {"type": "int", "connect.type": "int16"}], "default": null},
            {"name": "reportees_level", "type": ["null", {"type": "int", "connect.type": "int16"}], "default": null},
            {"name": "role_path", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},
            {"name": "role_path_slug", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},
            {"name": "role_label", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},
            {"name": "role_type", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},
            {"name": "userrole_operating_boundaries", "type": ["null", {"type": "string", "connect.version": 1, "connect.name": "io.debezium.data.Json"}], "default": null},
            {"name": "hierarchy", "type": ["null", {"type": "string", "connect.version": 1, "connect.name": "io.debezium.data.Json"}], "default": null},
            {"name": "created_at", "type": ["null", {"type": "long", "connect.version": 1, "connect.name": "io.debezium.time.MicroTimestamp"}], "default": null},
            {"name": "updated_at", "type": ["null", {"type": "long", "connect.version": 1, "connect.name": "io.debezium.time.MicroTimestamp"}], "default": null},
            {"name": "role_id", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},
            {"name": "_is_active", "type": ["null", "boolean"], "default": null},
            {"name": "userrole_metadata", "type": ["null", {"type": "string", "connect.version": 1, "connect.name": "io.debezium.data.Json"}], "default": null},
            {"name": "organisation_path_slug", "type": ["null", {"type": "string", "connect.version": 1, "connect.name": "io.debezium.data.Ltree"}], "default": null},
            {"name": "platforms", "type": ["null", {"type": "array", "items": ["null", "string"]}], "default": null},
            {"name": "userrole_created_at", "type": ["null", "int"], "default": null},
            {"name": "userrole_updated_at", "type": ["null", "int"], "default": null},
            {"name": "circle", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},
            {"name": "organisation_label", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},
            {"name": "__op", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},
            {"name": "__table", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},
            {"name": "__lsn", "type": ["null", "long"], "default": null},
            {"name": "__source_ts_ms", "type": ["null", "long"], "default": null}
        ]
    }
```

> panic: SourceTSMs: LSN: Table: Op: OrganisationLabel: Circle: UserroleUpdatedAt: UserroleCreatedAt: Platforms: OrganisationPathSlug: UserroleMetadata: IsActive: RoleID: UpdatedAt: CreatedAt: Hierarchy: UserroleOperatingBoundaries: RoleType: RoleLabel: RolePathSlug: RolePath: ReporteesLevel: RoleLevel: OperatingBoundaries: TenantID: OLMID: Email: MSISDN: Name: UserID: ReportingToID: OrganistionID: avro: string is unsupported for Avro union